# Is it possibel to inject php code to roundcube errors log file via LFI vulnerability?

Tags: web-application, php

i tried to inject php code to roundcube errors log file, with no success. i think there is something filtering injected php code.

Comment: This question will need a lot more detail to be answerable.  What was your lab setup (OS & Software versions, network layout, etc.)?  Which vulnerability (CVE or other external reference ID would be good) were you trying to exploit?

Comment: in addition to @Iszi, what is roundcube?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no. Stored code injection and LFI vulnerabilities are 2 different kinds of vulnerabilities.